# udev rules scripts has only read-only access to /, ubuntu16.10

Tags: 16.10, udev

I use udev rules to run shell-scripts when certain devices show up, after upgrading to ubuntu 16.10 the root filesystem is only available read-only from those scripts. In other words: a shell-script called from `/etc/udev/rules.d/NN-script.rules` can no longer write to `f.ex /tmp/a_file`

Is this a BUG ? or a desired change from previous versions of ubuntu ?

If desired, what is the prefered way to access / read-write from an udev script ?

Below excerpts from ubuntu 16.10

```
peter@u16.10:~$ ps -ef | grep udevd
root       368     1  0 13:09 ?        00:00:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
    
peter@u16.10:~$ head /proc/368/mounts
/dev/sda6 / ext4 ro,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered 0 0
```

--
And here from ubuntu 16.04

```
peter@16.04:~> ps -ef | grep udevd
root      2205     1  0 20:30 ?        00:00:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
        
peter@16.04:~> head /proc/2205/mounts
...
y/ROOT/ubuntu-16.04-y / zfs rw,relatime,xattr,noacl 0 0
```

A work-around that works is:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/udev restart
```

Comment: just to note: this seems to happen on rasbian 8.0 as well.

Comment: only as comment because i had the problem and were forced to get a valid solution.
qoute
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=179850
Systemd is (almost certainly) starting udev *before* remounting the disk as read/write.

for my case i restart udev via rc.local
But one really should have systemd restart udev once / is writeable

Comment: I agree with @DennisNolte about the cause, better to set a systemd script instead. Some thing you may try: remove your rules file, `sudo update-initramfs -u`, then put the rules file back, reboot to check.